# Unvisible google map in Android

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps, manifest

I using google map API in my android project, but it isn't visible. I wrote These codes:

1. Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.prmission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="... My Api ..."/>
```

2. Then, i wrote these Codes:

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(Map.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney,13));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've a code identically your and works. Just I've added one permission plus.

Try add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` permission.

And my `<meta-data>` is like this:

```
   <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="..." />
```